# Getting org related error while migrating old android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Getting :

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

**build.gradle file as below**

```
   buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '7.2.1'
        gms_version = '4.3.13'
        kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
        crashlytics_version = '2.8.1'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version "$gms_version" apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version "$crashlytics_version" apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

repositories {
    google()
}
```

**App level build.gradle :**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.brian.skyazul"
            minSdk 30
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.2"
    
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
       /* kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }*/
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:2.2.0'
        implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    }
```

What might be the issue?

**EDIT**

**Below is the complete stacktrace of error :**

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/jaiminmodi/StudioProjects/skyazul-android

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:2.2.0 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind is that a dependency you provided in the app level **build.gradle** file is not supported or couldn't be found. Can you provide the rest of the error log? Another possible problem might be with the gradle version specified within the project. Try downgrading that if the above suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: EDIT section added in question. please check.

Answer (score 1):

I just go through your problem and recommend you to try mavencentral() with google maven at your app level Gradle file, I hope it will work for you.

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
```